# Convert Ref{Cwstring}() to String

Tags: javascript, julia, chakracore

I am currently writing a `ccall` binding for the ChakraCore JavaScript engine and there is one function with this definition:

```js
CHAKRA_API JsStringToPointer(
    _In_ JsValueRef stringValue,
    _Outptr_result_buffer_(*stringLength) const WCHAR **stringPtr,
    _Out_ size_t *stringLength
)
```

So I create a Ref to a WCHAR via: `resultWC = Ref{Cwstring}()`

I tried a bunch of convert functions to get a `String` back, but nothing worked yet. I guess I need this: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.1/stdlib/strings/#Base.transcode

But `Base.transcode` wants a Vector/Array and I don't know how to do simple C-style casting in Julia for this case.

Any ideas how to turn a `Ref{Cwstring}()` into a `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, [it's a problem](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/28863).

Until that is fixed, you can add your own method:

```
function Base.unsafe_string(w::Cwstring)
    ptr = convert(Ptr{Cwchar_t}, w)
    ptr == C_NULL && throw(ArgumentError("cannot convert NULL to string"))
    buf = Cwchar_t[]
    i = 1
    while true
        c = unsafe_load(ptr, i)
        if c == 0
            break
        end
        push!(buf, c)
        i += 1
    end
    return String(transcode(UInt8, buf))
end
```

Then you can just call it by

```
unsafe_string(resultWC[])
```

Comment: Thanks, works also with Emojis, even tho Windows cmd.exe can't display most of them correctly in 2018. :D

Comment: At some point we hope to bundle our own terminal (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/7267), until then you could try something like http://cmder.net/